# How to adjust for known prognostic clinical or molecular confounders when using survival analysis methods that are not based on Cox regression?

Tags: svm, survival, random-forest, boosting, predictor

When using penalized Cox or Coxnet regression for survival analysis, it is possible to account and adjust for known prognostic clinical or molecular confounders by including them in your model as unpenalized features (via setting a penalty factor option or similar to 0 for those features).  But for survival analysis methods not based on Cox regression, such as survival SVM, survival gradient boosting, or survival random forest, how does one do the same?

Comment: Be aware that a variable being a covariate is not a sufficient condition to adjust for it. It needs to be a confounder - a concept that has been made much clearer via Pearl's causal diagram analysis. Sometimes, you need to NOT adjust for a variable!

Comment: My apologies that's what I meant - I will update the post

Comment: BTW thank you for the clarification!

Comment: Even if I have been working on machine learning for a while I still have some doubts about this issue: how to take confounders into account. I think that here we should think about the difference between prediction and causal modelling. During prediction, we do not need to think about confounders: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/442970/2719 I think that many machine learning models, such as random survival forests, are meant for prediction. Is this why "adjusting for confounders" is so difficult to find in machine learning literature?

Comment: Penalized regression-based models are also machine learning models and are used for prediction all the time. In survival analysis, this includes penalized Cox and Coxnet regression which are both used for prediction.  They both allow one to adjust for known prognostic factors via setting the penalty factor for those features to 0.  Read for example the Coxnet paper https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/v39i05.pdf

Comment: @Simone sorry I forgot to add that what is difficult to find, hence why I'm asking the question, is that adjusting for confounders is only mentioned when it comes to regression-based ML survival analysis models. As stated, there are other survival analysis methods, but I cannot find any guidance as to what should be done with known confounders when using them